# unable to find valid certification path to requested target this error is occuring after tls implementation in k8s env services

Tags: devops, self-signed, keycloak-services, tls1.3

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

tried implementating tls on k8s env deployed service using self signed certificate

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your self-signed CA chain (or the certificate) to the java truststore of your service which tries to connect to the HTTPS service.

Comment: how to do that is it on developer side or on k8s level?

Comment: You could use keytool to generate the truststore and then mount the generated truststore into the container to overwrite the default truststore.

Comment: we have created a jks file using a self-signed server certificate, after that we mention it in the docker file and properties file in Git and build the pipeline but still got the same error.

Comment: Are you referencing the truststore file correctly? My solution is working with replacing / mounting the default $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts file with the modified cacerts file in which the CA certificate was added. Good luck!